# Sqlite Database not deleting entry

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android app I create a Sqlite Table which contains information sorted by an id. So I added a method to delete entries again, by passing the id to the method. When I call the method from another class the correct id is received in the delete method, but for some reason the entry is not deleted. Is the delete method wrong maybe or did I set it up a false way?

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL3 = "TIME";
    public static final String COL4 = "SKILL";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " NAME TEXT," + " TIME TEXT," + " SKILL TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String name, String time, String skill) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, name);
        contentValues.put(COL3, time);
        contentValues.put(COL4, skill);
        Log.d("skill", skill);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void deleteTask(int rowId)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d("delete id", String.valueOf(rowId));

        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + rowId + "'";

         db.execSQL(query);
    }


    public Cursor getListContents(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, TIME, SKILL FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, instead of `execSql()` use the `delete()` method which returns the number of rows that were deleted, like this: `int rowsDeleted = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "COL1 = ?", new String[] {rowId});`. Check the value of `rowsDeleted` after the statement is executed.

Comment: I tried it before with the `delete` method but didn't get it to work. When I try it like you did, I get an error because the `rowId` in the end is an `int` which is tried to be put into a `String[]`. Can you tell me how to change it, too?

Comment: Instead of `{rowId}`, do `{String.valueOf(rowId)}`

Comment: It kind of works only half way. It deletes entries at least, but more like randomly. When I tap an element, I can see what ID it has and when I call the delete method I see for what ID the method is called, but then it sometimes doesn't delete at all and sometimes it deletes the above element..do you have an idea why that could be as well?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code in your SqlOpenHelper class. I guess you use a ListView or RecyclerView. Your problem is getting the right id to delete.

Comment: You are right, I did a mistake fetching the variable correctly. Thank you for your help!
If you write it as an answer I'll gladly accept it of course

Comment: It's fine......